# Java TCP byteArray transfering using buffer and threading

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, buffer, arrays

So basically what I want to do is: Create a very simple multithreaded TCP server that can connect to several clients at once. This using threads and transferring messages through Byte[] and returning an echo of the message.

I have never touched anything related to server programming or TCP before, so I expect to have made a lot of mistakes. I am open for improvement and suggestions.

I made a simple Server class:

```
public class TCPEchoServer {
public static final int SERVERPORT = 4950;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

    while (true) {
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        Runnable connectionHandler = new TCPConnectionHandler(clientSocket);
        new Thread(connectionHandler).start();

    }
}
}
```

And the connection handler class:

```
public class TCPConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
private final Socket clientSocket;
private int msgLength = 0;
private byte[] data;

public TCPConnectionHandler(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);

        msgLength = dis.readInt();
        data = new byte[msgLength];
        if (msgLength > 0) {
            dis.readFully(data);
        }
        String message = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Message recieved: " + message);

        outToClient.writeBytes(String.valueOf(data));
        clientSocket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.printf("Could not listen on port: " + clientSocket.getLocalPort());
    }
}
}
```

And the Client class:

```
public class TCPEchoClient {

public static final int MYPORT = 0;
public static int BUFFSIZE = 0;
public static Socket socket;

public static final String MSG = "An Echo Message! LOL";
public static String RETURNMSG = "";

public static final byte[] messageByteArr = MSG.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "^(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$");


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (args.length != 4) {
        System.err.printf("ERROR: The EchoClient expects 4 parameter inputs:");
        System.out.printf("IP address, Port number, message rate (msg/second).");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (!isValidIP(args[0])) {
        System.out.printf("ERROR: The entered IP address is not a valid IPv4 address.");
        System.out.printf("Please enter a valid IPv4 address as the first argument.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (Integer.parseInt(args[1]) < 0 || Integer.parseInt(args[1]) > 65535) { //If the portnumber is negative or bigger than the highest portnumber (unsigned 16-bit integer)
        System.out.printf("ERROR: The chosen portnumber is outside the available range.");
        System.out.printf("Expected portnumbers: 0-65535");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (Integer.parseInt(args[3]) < messageByteArr.length) {
        System.out.println("Buffer size can not be smaller than the message size.");
        System.out.println("Current message size: " + messageByteArr.length);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BUFFSIZE = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFSIZE];

    DataOutputStream outToServer = null;
    BufferedReader serverEcho = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        serverEcho = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Unknown host address: " + args[0]);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not access port " + Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int msgLength = 0;
    int msgStart = 0;
    if (msgLength < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative length not allowed.");
    }
    if (msgStart < 0 || msgStart >= messageByteArr.length) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of bounds: " + msgStart);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(args[2]); i++) {
        outToServer.writeInt(msgLength);
        if (msgLength > 0) {
            outToServer.write(messageByteArr, msgStart, msgLength);
            System.out.println("Message sent: " + MSG);
        }
        RETURNMSG = serverEcho.readLine();
        System.out.println("ECHO MESSAGE: " + RETURNMSG);
    }
    socket.close();

}
private static boolean isValidIP(final String ip) {
    return PATTERN.matcher(ip).matches();
}
```

}

I ran into a problem just now as well, the print outs worked before on the client and sever, but now when a message is sent. Nothing happens at all.

My main question is how I can incorporate a buffer and use it when sending and receiving messages.

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop in the client that will wait args[2] times the RETURNMSG, the server will send this message only once. The RETURNMSG reading code should be outside (after) the `for` loop.

You should flush the buffer once you've finished writing in it.

This should be done in both client and server, since your client will wait the RETURNMSG forever depending how your protocol will evolve in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I changed the code with your words in mind. But how can I Incorporate a byte[] buffer that is set as an argument? I have made a byte[] that I can assign to the message i want to send. But how do I use it in relation to send and receive the message and echo? In my understanding, TCP "chops" the message up in segments if the buffer size is smaller than the message itself.